# How to make an alias and work in sh for all users (not in bash)?

Tags: bash, alias, sh

My question maybe is silly, but how can I make an `alias` so as to work
in `sh` for all users?

I know that I can put an alias, let say this one:

```
alias ls='ls -l'
```

in `/etc/bash.bashrc` so as to work in `bash` but what is the equivalent
for the `sh`?

I tried to put is in `/etc/profile` but doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't `sh` only a symbolic link to your preferred shell?

Comment: `which sh`: /bin/sh

Comment: For me `which sh` still says `sh` even though it's a symlink to bash. `realpath sh` reveals otherwise, however.

Answer (score 0):

After put your alias in `/etc/profile` exec follow command:

> source /etc/profile

Try this solution and feedback here.

Comment: I have done it, but still doesn't work..

Comment: `source` doesn't work in most (all?) implementations of `sh`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588636). `. /etc/profile` should work.

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

In general you can't.

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells#General_characteristics) says that for the POSIX shell (`sh`) startup/shutdown scripts are

> Unspecified (`.profile` given as an example)

And I haven't found even this example in [POSIX.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nframe.html).

In practice `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` are sourced (at least in Linux, by few `sh` implementations I worked with). In the context of your question the problem is they are sourced only by login shells. Not every shell is a login shell. Not every interactive shell is a login shell.

Additionally the sole [concept of login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175/108618) seems not to be defined by POSIX (somebody correct me if I'm wrong). [This document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) doesn't specify `-l` as a required option of `sh`, although in practice many implementations use it to force the login shell behavior.

Even if `/etc/profile` was parsed by a (((…-)grand-)grand)parent process of your current non-login shell, there's no way you inherited aliases defined there because aliases cannot be exported; they don't propagate within the environment like exported variables do. A function instead of an alias [won't help you either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29239806).

My conclusion is: in general you cannot expect `sh` to source any file automatically. To make every `sh` source a specific file where your alias is defined, you need to find (or write) an implementation that does this.

A user can source a file by hand with `. /path/to/file`.

---

There is, however, an approach that allows you to make `ls` work like `ls -l`. You can do this by a wrapper script that replaces `/bin/ls` and `exec`-s to `/bin/real_ls -l "$@"` (where `real_ls` is the real `ls` renamed). Such approach is not uncommon, compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1281643/432690). There are disadvantages and pitfalls though.

- If the real `ls` is a symlink to a swiss-army-knife binary like `busybox`, the binary will get confused if it's called by the name `real_ls`.

This is easily avoided by using `/another/dir/ls` instead of `real_ls`. But even then

- a future system update may overwrite your custom `/bin/ls`.

Now this can be avoided by leaving the real `ls` as `/bin/ls`, placing your custom `ls` in `/another/dir` and adding the `/another/dir` to `PATH` as the first entry for all users (this you can usually do via `/etc/profile`). But then

- every script that uses `ls` and the modified `PATH` variable (as opposed to `/bin/ls`, full path) will find your custom `ls`.

This may backfire easily. If you had an alias, a script (running in a subshell, not sourced) wouldn't inherit it. A script can define an independent alias for itself, anyway `ls` inside the script doesn't depend on any "external" alias; but it may easily depend on whatever executable `ls` resolves to. Changing the behavior of `ls` for every user may upset them a little, they will hopefully adjust in their interactive shells though. But changing the behavior of `ls` for every existing script is *wrong*, especially because `ls` is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) and the definition explicitly states its behavior should depend on the presence of `-l` option. Replacing `ls` with your custom `ls` where `ls` and `ls -l` are equivalent will break its POSIX compliance.

OK, `ls` is not the best example here, because [one shouldn't parse its output anyway](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). On the other hand you never know in what ways users (mis)use any tool.

Also note it's possible to have an *implementation* of `sh` where `ls` is a builtin. In this case mangling with `/bin/ls` or/and `PATH` cannot override what plain `ls` means; an alias or a function can.

---

If you'd like to have a "global" alias with *another* name, e.g.

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

then switching to a `/bin/ll` script looks perfectly safe to me. `ls` stays intact, nothing is broken. The script may look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ls -l "$@"
```