# What is the default monitoring port for autossh?

Tags: linux, ssh

The [autossh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh) command has the following `-M` option:

```
   -M port[:echo_port]

specifies the base monitoring port to use. Without the echo port, this port
and the port immediately above it ( port + 1) should be something nothing else
is using. autossh will send test data on the base monitoring port, and receive
it back on the port above. For example, if you specify "-M 20000", autossh will
set up forwards so that it can send data on port 20000 and receive it back on
20001.
```

Alternatively, you can specify the same behavior using the `AUTOSSH_PORT` environment variable.

My question is the following:

If neither the `-M` option nor the env variable is specified, what port is used for monitoring? Or is the behavior disabled?  The documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If neither the `-M` option nor the env variable is specified, what port is used for monitoring?

In my several tests on Kubuntu client, **random** high ports were used in a range about (my estimation) `30000-60000`. Compare: [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). I mean the first (`port`) was randomly chosen, the second one was just above it (`port+1`).

`-M` without a proper argument (`autossh -M -- …` or `autossh -M foo …`) exits immediately; it doesn't print any error but the exit status is `1`.

`autossh -M 0 …` indeed disables the feature.

#### But…

I tried to analyze the source and haven't found this randomness. Then I discovered this:

```
$ type autossh
autossh is /usr/bin/autossh
$ file /usr/bin/autossh
/usr/bin/autossh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
$ head -n 4 /usr/bin/autossh
#!/bin/sh
# little wrapper to choose a random port for autossh, falling back to $fallback_port

fallback_port="21021"
$ tail -n 1 /usr/bin/autossh
exec /usr/lib/autossh/autossh "$@"
$ file /usr/lib/autossh/autossh
/usr/lib/autossh/autossh: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, …
```

This means in Kubuntu I have a wrapper that randomly chooses a port, if it's not specified by `-M` nor `AUTOSSH_PORT`. I'm not posting the full code here but I've read it: if the wrapper cannot randomly hit an unused pair of ports (i.e. `port` and `port+1`) in 42 tries then it finally tries `21021` and `21022`; if these ports cannot be used, the wrapper exits with an error.

If the wrapper succeeds, it exports the first port as `AUTOSSH_PORT` and runs the real `autossh` (`/usr/lib/autossh/autossh`). This executable *requires* `-M` or `AUTOSSH_PORT`, otherwise it won't run.

My final answer is: **there is no default monitoring port for *vanilla* `autossh`**. You have to set `AUTOSSH_PORT` or use `-M`. This is inconvenient, hence the wrapper. You may or may not have one in your Linux. It's possible some flavors of Linux use wrappers that set and use a fixed default port.

Answer (score 3):

There is no default port because it can be *any* unused port on the remote system however it also must be open. However, I don't think there's any 'sane' use case for it, as documented [here](https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/) you might as well just use SSH's own stay alive options instead:

`autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -L 5000:localhost:3306 user@randomhost.org`

This would 'disconnect' after 90 seconds of no response from the server, and then AutoSSH would reconnect automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for the default port, if it is indeed unspecified.

Comment: It is unspecified, because it can literally be any port.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I reflected your last comment in a pending edit to your answer.